# Is there anything "incorrect" about running multiple database platforms at once?

Tags: database, graph, relational-database

Let's say I have an application that works with different kinds of data. Each kind of data is unique, and the different kind are only tangentially related to each other. It may be very difficult to get one kind to map to a RDMS, and another kind to a graph database. Is there any real harm in running multiple database platforms to address the various needs of the application?

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of application specific issues.  Will the data stores be talking to each other directly?  Or, will they be communicating through the application?

The major issues have to do with maintenance over time.  If the different databases are running on the same server, then you have maintenance issues.  A new server OS patch comes in, but only some of the software works with the new patch.  Do you install it or not?  What if you *need* it for some other reason?

Similarly, if all the software is running on a single server, then you might need a larger server because you have more software.  You will be paying more for products that are priced by the size of the server, even though the extra compute power is going somewhere else.

In some cases, you might need to use different products.  However, it is often more practical to use one product a bit sub-optimally, rather than maintain a system with a profusion of best-for-a-single-purpose software componenents.

Comment: And databases like to be the only thing on the server due to how they gobble up all available memory, you may have multiple database applications trying to use all the memory for instance. It may be preferable to have each type of database on it's own server.

Comment: Well, what if each database system got it's own server? This application is most likely going to be run on cloud or virtual servers, so each one can easily get its own. They won't be talking to each other directly; that's the reason there would be multiple databases. The data difference between the systems would be too great to justify a single relational database, especially since some data won't map well there.

Comment: If you are making the investment in additional servers, then there are some good arguments for using appropriate software in each case.  For instance, you can scale the different components individually.  I advocate being conservative when adding new software components, but not being unreasonable.  If there is a need, then add a component.  Just consider the maintenance issues moving forward as you balance trade-offs.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's no major issue with it as long as you watch for injections and other security issues (i don't know how you pass your data to DB)

Answer (score 0):

Its technically possible and would work, however the person or team building the system would need to have all the skills to develop/test/deploy/maintain/backup the database with various mechanisms, procedures and future development and upgrade paths for each (duplicated for each type of data/database). I would certainly try and minimise those mechanisms and procedures.